# Custom annotation that will include list of other annotations

Tags: kotlin, annotations

I wanna create a custom annotation, for example, `@Dev`. But also want this annotation to include few other regular annotation "inside", like `@Suppress("unused")`, `@Suppress("PropertyName")`, `@Suppress("DEPRECATION")`, etc..
Is there any way to achieve such a result somehow?